# Image not loading on google chrome

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an image on my html that is not displayed on Chrome. If I inspect the img tag, I can see a preview, so the img url is correct. If, for example, I change some css attribute (inspecting), like img height, image also shows. The issue is that it doesn´t load when the page is ready. It works fine on Edge.

Comment: Reset your cache or do ctrl+f5

Comment: I tried also incognito, but it didn´t work

Comment: Looks like a css issue as you said changing the some attributes displays the image. What is default width or height of image when it is initially rendered?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and share here?

Comment: Actually, I don´t change attributes, I just check/uncheck, but in the end I don´t add nothing new

Comment: I found the issue, I was using "height:100%" on img tag. I changed that to a fixed value, 40pt, and now it´s loading fine. Thanks for your help